# keep input data when changing language in localized ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC Localized application based on this tutoriel http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4d9083/globalization-and-localization-in-asp-net-mvc-4/.

It works fine, but if user type data in a form and change the language before submitting the form, the localized strings are well changed but the date entered in the form are lost.

I think the only way is to submit the form when the language link is clicked and in the server side, after changing the UICulture,  use the submitted data to display the same view, but the submit will not happen if there is invalid data.
In webforms there is not such a problem thanks to the viewstate and the (causesvalidation=false).

Functionnaly, the data loss may be acceptable (the user choose the wrong time to change the language), but is there any elegant way to avoid the data loss ?!

Comment: YOu should write a client side solution to this problem. You can store the form data on the browser local storage and read it later.

Comment: your suggestion looks like a trap

Comment: what's the problem in storing on browser? I may be able to help if you elaborate.

Comment: it was a joke about your nickname but I'm not sure your solution is so suitable for me, because it takes to do something (read and set the value ) for every input in my form, i'm still hoping to find more efficient.

Comment: actually it depends on the solution that you use to translate. For ex if you are using google translate, it doesn't even touch your form entries. Also i am not able to think of a solution where you won't need to do something with every value. Even if you make a server side solution, then also you would end up fetching every value and posting on the server.

Comment: Think you didn't understand my situation, I'm using .resx files to bring localized strings. please see the link in my question.